# How do I create a database record that can repeatedly be copied, but also edited?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms

This is my first  post here, sorry if I can't be specific enough. I'm just starting out with ruby on rails and am trying to build myself a journal app to keep track of workouts. I want to be able to create a workout which contains an indefinite amount of lifts (bench, leg press, etc.) and each of those lifts needs a number of sets, and a number of repetitions. I want the user to be able to add create a workout consisting of say 8 lifts, and then be able to repeatedly copy that to log every day a workout with the sets and reps modified. I know I need a workout model, and then a lift model, I guess I just need help on getting the associations right. Again I can provide more clarity as to what I am trying to do, I don't have that much programming experience, but am figuring it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you should consider three models:

- `Lift` model - one for each exercise (Bench, Leg Press, Squat). `has_and_belongs_to_many :workouts`
- `Workout` model - one for each type of workout. `has_and_belongs_to_many :lifts`.
- `WorkoutExecution` model - one for each time a user does a workout. `belongs_to :user` and `belongs_to :workout`.

(You'll of course need a `User` model, too, if you're allowing users to login and create workouts/ register the execution of a workout).

This way, a user can create a workout in advance (or say, 3 workouts they have in their program), then register the execution of that workout each time they do it by creating an `WorkoutExecution` record.

This is a fairly complex set of relationships for your first project! Be sure to read the [Rails guide on Associations](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) to help get your head around it.

Comment: Thanks for the info, that makes more sense, I might have to simplify my project to get myself going.